# Is it possible to install an OS on USB flash memory of 4 GB

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, xubuntu, lubuntu

I was asked to install an OS on an USB while I have only a flash memory of 4 GB.
Is there any OS product with a nice GUI like UBUNTU in which I can boot it from the USB? 
If so, how to install it and boot it from my USB?

Comment: Ubuntu should fit on a USB (just use the normal way of creating a bootable installation USB). If you want to make it persistent: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent Note that you probably won't have a lot of space left - if you use a lightweight variant of Ubuntu, such as Ubuntu MATE, the performance will probably be better, and you'll have more free space left.

Comment: No, the installer will complain that the root partition is too small, and ask for a 5.3GB partition.

Answer (score 1):

From our [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick):

> **Notes about size**

- 1 GB is enough for a live USB flash drive made from a 'CD size' iso file. But unless you already have a 1 GB drive, you are recommended to get one with at least 2 GB, hence the general recommendation above.
- 2 GB is enough for 'CD size' iso files as well as many but not all 'DVD size' iso files.
- If you want a persistent live system with a decent size casper-rw storage, you need at least 4 GB (2 GB is possible, but might soon run out of space).
- If you want an installed system you need at least 8 GB (4 GB is possible with Lubuntu, but might soon run out of space). In the beginning of 2014, it seems that there are no really fast pendrives below 16 GB. If you want a fast system, install it into a pendrive that performs well in a test, even if it is 'bigger than necessary'.

---

So the answer is yes, but with limitations; not just on size but also on speed (4Gb USB are slow). 8Gb is recommended and 16Gb preferred.

Answer (score 1):

A Persistent install will use about 1GB for the system, (the size of the iso), with about 3GB left over for persistence.